# How to create a AWS Kubernetes cluster (EKS) using Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I am attempting to create a Kubernetes cluster using Fargate.

I am using eksctl with a .config file (below).

If you have a config file to create a basic Kubernetes cluster using Fargate, please share.

I am getting a ROLLBACK, I do not understand what this error message means.

```
No export named eksctl-<name>-cluster::SubnetsPublic found. 

Rollback requested by user.

ROLLBACK_COMPLETE
```

**config file:**

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: test-kb-cluster-w-fg-profile
  region: us-west-2
  version: "1.19"

vpc:
  subnets:
    private:
      us-west-2a: { id: subnet-<hash> }
      us-west-2b: { id: subnet-<hash> }
      us-west-2c: { id: subnet-<hash> }

nodeGroups:
  - name: test-eks-linux-nodes 
    instanceType: t2.micro
    desiredCapacity: 1

fargateProfiles:
  - name: test-fp-default
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "default" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: default
      # All workloads in the "kube-system" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: kube-system
```

If y

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the subnets that you mentioned are correct. For me, it was incorrect subnets which caused the same issue.

Also, I notice that you are prvoviding only private subnets.  You might want to see if you need to set privateNetworking to true under NG defination.

`privateNetworking: true # if only 'Private' subnets are given, this must be enabled`

Ref: https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/blob/main/examples/04-existing-vpc.yaml

Comment: Even though you are using only private VPC subnets, you *also* have to toggle `--node-private-networking`?